# Install setup.py dependencies before copying over the complete project

Tags: python, docker, pip

My Dockerfile used to be like this:

```
...
COPY . /source/
RUN pip install -e .
...
```

However, I'd like to minimize the time it takes to complete a docker build by doing `COPY` of only `setup.py` before the rest of the code is copied. This way pip install can be done in between, so it's not required to do the install every time the code changes, only when setup.py does.

```
...
COPY setup.py /source/
RUN pip install -e .
COPY . /source/
...
```

Do you see anything problematic with using `pip install -e .` in a production docker image with regards to efficiency? Is there a better way of doing it? I'm wondering because I've only seen `-e` being used on development machines, never in production.

Answer (score 1):

Why would you prefer installing with `pip install -e .` rather than `pip install .` in production? If you want to ability to modify code without restarting container, you will do that in development only I guess. In production, it is safer to allow code to be changed only after container restart.

Concerning the way you build your images, if you want to speed up build and have a clean final image you can try with multi-stage build:

Use multi-stage build to create wheels for each dependancy in first stage, and install package and dependencies in second step.

```
FROM python:3-alpine as wheels_builder

RUN mkdir /wheels

COPY setup.py ./setup.py

# Filter the packages not needed to build your sources 
RUN apk add --update --no-cache gcc g++ gfortran openblas-dev musl-dev linux-headers libffi-dev openssl-dev sqlite-dev tk-dev readline-dev ncurses-dev

RUN pip install -U pip wheel setuptools && pip wheel . --wheel-dir=/wheels


# Second step of build

FROM python:3-alpine as prod

COPY --from=base /wheels /tmp/wheels

COPY  . /source

RUN pip install --no-index --find-links=/tmp/wheels/. .
```

This way no dependency is installed on final container.

Moreover if you don't change your `setup.py` file, I think that docker will use cache and you won't have to rebuild the wheels_builder image.

It should speed up the process of recreating docker images for you project. Installation from wheel is a matter of milliseconds, compared to tens of seconds needed to build from source.

I don't know if it will help you but at least it's a start, you can change it to fit your needs.